# Failure to find libgpgme.so while building rosbag_storage

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building on FreeBSD from source, using `catkin_make_isolated`.

When I'm building `rosbag_storage` the linker fails to find `libgpgme.so` with the error `ld: cannot find -lgpgme`.

I have installed the `libgpgme` package and confirm `libgpgme.so` is in `/usr/local/lib`.  Apparently, this is not a default search path (on FreeBSD only?) for libraries to link, however.

I added `link_directories(/usr/local/lib)` at the top of the `CMakeList.txt` file for `rosbag_storage`.  The linker now finds the library and `rosbag_storage` builds just fine.

Is there a better way to do this than to modify the `CMakeList.txt`?  I'm trying to keep the FreeBSD build process as close as possible to the Ubuntu process, so the fewer manual modifications I have to make, the better.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342313/failure-to-find-libgpgme.so-while-building-rosbag_storage/) by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-22**:
As much as you're encountering this while building a ROS package, I don't believe this is a ROS problem necessarily, but more a general CMake how-to-link-a-library problem (but the specifically with `libgpgme`).

Could you try creating an MWE which just tries to link `libgpgme` to a test program? If that also doesn't work, it would seem to be a general issue.

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-01-22**:
It does appear to be a general issue with FreeBSD not automatically including `/usr/local/lib`.

My question, more specifically, is whether there is a way for me to specify link directories at build time so I don't have to modify the `CMakeList.txt` file.

I suppose this is a `catkin` question...?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-22**:
No. That would make it a CMake one. Catkin doesn't do anything with this. And I guess the keyword would be: specify a library *search path*. Not link directories (as that is the name of the CMake command).

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-01-22**:
I'm new to cmake (and catkin), so I'm having a hard time either understanding or implementing your response.

For `rosbag_storage`, the `CMakeList.txt` file includes the following:

`set(AES_ENCRYPT_LIBRARIES "crypto" "gpgme")`

The variable is then used as follows:

`target_link_libraries(rosbag_storage ... ${AES_ENCRYPT_LIBRARIES})`

I cannot find a command line argument to pass to cmake (via catkin_make) to allow the linker to find `libgpgme`.  I continue to get the error `ld: cannot find -lgpgme`.

The only thing I've found that works is to place `link_directories(/usr/local/lib)` in `CMakeList.txt` before `set(AES_ENCRYPT_LIBRARIES "crypto" "gpgme")`.

I can limit the superfluity of this with a check for the target OS:

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "FreeBSD")
    link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To close this out:

I fixed this (for both my Mac and FreeBSD builds), by using cmake's `find_library` function in the CMakeList.txt file.

You can see my full solution here:  https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1866

There is also a (currently pending) pull request:  https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1867

---

Originally posted by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) with karma: 111 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-30**:
Thanks for submitting the PR and fixing this.

And thanks for reporting back here on ROS Answers.